# Definition of Random Variable as Existence of Radon-Nikodym Derivative

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In elementary probability, a random variable is defined as a map from the sample space to reals.

Consider a random variable $X$, and its law of probability $P_X$. Denote the Lebesgue measure as $\lambda$.

In measure theory, I realized the *existence* of the probability density function is central in defining the random variable to be continuous.

*My Questions*

(1) can we characterize a continuous random variable as:

> A random variable $X$ is continuous if there exists a Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{dP_X}{d\lambda}$, which is denoted as $f_X$, satisfying $P(X\leq x)=\int_{\infty}^xf_X(t)dt$.

(2) On a related note, how do we check if there exists such R-N derivative? Using the R-N theorem that says if $P_X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$, then there exists a R-N derivative. But as a practical matter, how do we check: On a measure space $(\Omega,F,\lambda)$, we say $P_X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, if for all $E\in F$,

$$\lambda(E)=0\implies P_X(E)=0.$$

Is it logistically possible to check this for all Borel sets?

Comment: it is not needed to say that $f$ is a Radon-Nikodym derivative, it is enough to say that some continuous function such that $P(X\leqslant c)=\int_{-\infty }^c f(x)\mathop{}\!d x$ exists. Of course it is a Radon-Nikodym derivative because $f(x)\mathop{}\!d x$ is a measure

Comment: Can someone fully respond to my question? Thanks.,

Comment: @Masacroso Ok, I understand what you wrote, but that still doesn't answer my question (1). My question is "can", so it the above characterization valid?